# MySQL not counting rows based on date values properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I'm trying to count the amount of rows that have the same date value, but it won't do that. I can't get it to count higher then 3 when I know there are  rows with the same date value. Here is my code:

```
$getDate = getdate();

$d = $getDate['mday'];
$m = $getDate['mon'];
$y = $getDate['year'];

$date = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;


$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites WHERE date='$date'";
mysql_select_db('garrettl_awards');
$total = mysql_query( $query, $conn );

$loop = $total/4;
echo $loop;
```

Here is a picture of my database table :

[image: database table]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites WHERE date>='$date' AND date < ('$date' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

It will deal with the possibility that your `date` column contains some values that aren't precisely at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, may work for you;)

If the format of `$date` is yyyy-mm-dd like(2016-05-01):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites WHERE date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d')='$date'
```

Or the format is yyyy-m-d like (2016-5-1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites WHERE date_format(date, '%Y-%c-%e')='$date'
```

**Edited:**

Try this;)

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites WHERE date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d')='" . $date . "'";
```

Comment: @Garrett Could you post some sample data please?

Comment: Yeah like what? sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @Garrett like data in your table and your expected data.

Comment: I included on in my question, can you not see it?

Comment: @Garrett your post is not in correct format, so I cant see it, anyway I've edited for you, and what's the type of your column `date`?

Comment: Thanks, what did I do wrong with formatting? And the type of the date column is "date"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare "textually" two values, make sure they are formatted the same way :

Format your date parameter :

```
// For month and day to be on 2 digits
$d = sprintf("%'.02d", $getDate['mday']);
$m = sprintf("%'.02d", $getDate['mday']);
```

And dates you have in your database :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM websites WHERE date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d')='$date'
```

It should resolve your problem.